# Git clones wrong repository

Tags: git, github, clone

We have several Git repositories stored remotely in GitHub. I am using git bash to clone a repository. Repository A clones completely fine from a URL I am taking from GitHub, but when using the URL for repository B, I still get the source of repository A. However much I try I am unable to pull down the code from repository B.

Has anyone had any similar behaviour?

Comment: Maybe share the commands you're using?

Comment: Thanks Chris. I was using "git clone https://github.com/....

However, I've since worked out what the issue was. My git config was forcing [remote "origin"] to always point to repository A.

Comment: Did you have your remote specified in $HOME/.gitconfig rather than in the clone's .git/config ?

Answer (score 8):

Just delete the remote/origin assignment in the `~/.gitconfig` file and everything will go correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you remove your git remote for origin and re add it

```
git remote rm origin

git remote add (your remote here)
```

see https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-remote

Answer (score 0):

Using Linux Fedora 20, and I've been through this problem.
I took a **rm-rf** (make a backup please) on the repository folder and initialized it again. After get project again with **git pull origin master** command.
This worked for me.